# Convert non valid json to a valid json in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a json file that is appended on the go using powershell varables. but file populates like this
I know this is not a valid json file, hence my problem
Well i dont know what more details i can say for this post to be valid, as i like to go straight to the point. Convert one non-valid json to a valid json file. But somehow the stupid system keeps saying i need to put more info. This is actually a simple question, yes i did put a lot of code, but i want to show what i want to achieve.

```
{
     "B21E7":  [
                 {
                    "car":  35761,
                     "tire":  1
                 },
                 {
                     "car":  36532,
                     "tire":  1
                 }
                 ]
 }
 {
     "B21E7":  [
                 {
                     "car":  35761,
                     "tire":  1
                 },
                 {
                     "car":  36532,
                     "tire":  1
                 }
                 ]
 }
```

i need to convert to a valid json like this

```
{
 "B21E7":  [
             {
                 "car":  35761,
                 "tire":  1
             },
             {
                 "car":  36532,
                 "tire":  1
             }
             ],
 "B21E7":  [
             {
                 "car":  35761,
                 "tire":  1
             },
             {
                 "car":  36532,
                 "tire":  1
             }
             ]
}
```

heres how i populate file

```
$track = @(
@{$code.keyFull = $values }
Write-Output $track | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File -FilePath track .json -Append
```

been searching and trying many code example to no avail
any help would be helpful.

Comment: How did invalid json get generated?  The real issue is somebody generated something that was invalid.

Comment: Instead of just slapping a second json document onto the end of the first you need to read in the first json file, merge the new values *in-memory* and then replace the *entire* contents of the file with the resulting dataset converted back to json - something like this: ```$data = Get-Content -Raw "track.json" | ConvertFrom-Json; ... merge new records into $data here ...; $data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | Set-Content "track.json"```

Comment: Tried your code after the Write-output. Didnt work. If i remove -Append, only the last inserted code shows. Even tried to send to different file name but only the 1st json is used.

Comment: `(Get-Content track.json -Raw) -replace '(?m)}\s+{', ',' |ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: OMG < i cant believe i said that, but you done it. your code @MathiasR.Jessen + mclayton code together fix my issue. ***** Thank you so much